# Get every element with a specific (data-) attribute in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to test a page using CasperJS. Are there any possibilities to get every element (paragraphs) which contains attribute data-...? 
After that, I need to compare this attribute with the inner HTML, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to retrieve the representations of all of the elements you're interested in. This can be done with [`casper.getElementsInfo(selector)`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo):

```
var elements = casper.getElementsInfo("p[data-whatever]");
```

This will give you all `<p>` elements on the page that have a `data-whatever` attribute set. If you want to filter that by the values of the `data-whatever` attributes, then you need to use the [attribute selectors](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) according to your needs.

The `getElementsInfo()` function contains very much useful information, but doesn't contain the actual elements that you want to use. It only contains a representation as an array.

You can iterate over those element representations and run your operations on them. You said you want to *"compare this attribute with inner HTML"*. This can be done in this way:

```
elements.forEach(function(element){
    if (element.attributes["data-whatever"] === element.html) {
        casper.echo("data attribute and content are exactly equal");
    } else {
        casper.echo("data attribute and content are different");
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that you can do this on the elements directly with the normal DOM functions, but then you would have to do this inside of [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate), because PhantomJS (which CasperJS is built upon) has two contexts and the page context is sandboxed. Also, you cannot return DOM nodes from the [page context](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html).